# Passing function from component to service

Tags: angular

I am trying to access the data from service,but it can only be accessed if I call one of component function in service function.Is there anything that I can do?

I tried using callback inside observable but that's not working.Is it a good practice to import component inside service and then call a function?

```
service.ts:
 serviceFunc1(){
   //I will get some data from here after subscribing
   this.serviceFunc2();
   CompoFunc1(); // Not able to do
   //Calling CompoFunc1() to get items variable(please read entire you'll get it)
}
  serviceFunc2(){
    //I will use the data that came from serviceFunc1() inside api(loop)
    //After subscribing the data I will get some data, that data I will be storing in some variable(assume variable is items)
  }

Component.ts:
  CompoFunc1(){
     //Now I need to acces the variable items inside this component
     //So this.service.items;
     //But to get items I need to call CompoFunc1() inside serviceFunc1 after serviceFunc2()  
 }
 ngOnInit(){
  this.service.serviceFunc1();
}
```

If any question, feel free to ask.

I just want to access items variable inside component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Comment: I'm still not getting it

Comment: I am not getting at all what you are asking or trying to do. I guess is that whatever it is you are making it much more complicated than it needs to be. I recommend you [edit] your question and add some actual business logic/reasoning for what it is you are trying to accomplish and why instead of focusing on func1 func2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your service should *not* normally call into your component. If it needs data from the component, pass that data from the component to the service in the `this.service.serviceFunc1(myData)` call.

If you need to do something in the component after the service call, add the code *after* the call to the service.

**Service**

Call the `http.get` here, but don't subscribe

```
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
  }
```

**Component**

Call the service here, subscribe, and perform any other required operations.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      products => {
        this.products = products;
        // Do whatever else needs to be done in the component after receiving the data
      }
    );
  }
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: mam actually I need to get the value from serivces to component.But I am not able to get it, because the value isn't stored in it.I need to somehow call compoFunc1() after serviceFunc()2, so I can access the data after the value is stored in it.

Comment: Can you build a simple stackblitz that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve with a bit more code than you have in your question?

Comment: I'm not able to share

Comment: ?? We don't need/want your application. Just dummy up something that demonstrates your issue with a bit more logic than what you have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subscribe to anything from your component.

Within the service, set a function to get the data from the component.

```
public getData(args: any){
    this.data = args;
}
```

In your component, send data to the service like so:

```
this.service.getData(myDataFromComponent);
```

The service now has the myDataFromComponent dataset stored as this.data.

You mentioned using an API, so I'm assuming an observable is returned.

```
serviceFunc1(args: any) {
    //This is where you work your magic with the data
}

serviceFunc2(args: any) {
    //Code to process the secondary data here:
}
```

Make sure you nest your functions so as have that return prior to continuing with your code:

```
serviceFunc3() {
    this.serviceFunc1.pipe(
      switchMap( results => {
        this.finalAnswer = this.serviceFunc2(results);
        //Additional processing/handling of data;
      })
    );
}
```